# Adding Core/Abs exercises to my routine

Tags: workout-routines, gym, abdominals, upper-body-workout

My workout routine is as follows:

Chest/Biceps

Legs

Back/Triceps

Shoulders

and Legs again.

I want to include some good core/ab exercises, please recommend some and tell me on which routines should I add them.

I am a skinny person, looking to build mass. I weigh 57 Kgs and am 180 cm tall.

In the past I have been doing planks, crunches, decline board sit up, leg raises. Also is it possible for me have those engraved ab muscles?

Answer (score 1):

If you are skinny.  It's possible to have defined abs, as usually it's the layer of fat that causes the problem.  You need to make sure all ab muscles are worked.

The plank works the transverse abdominus.   Leg raises and crunches the rectus abdominus.  You could do with adding something for obliques, depending on your level I would go for a russian twist, side plank or lateral crunches.  It would also be worth adding some back raises to make sure you are working the whole of your truck and don't become unbalanced.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to be doing an [abs workout](https://sportshuge.com/85-exclusive-abs-workouts-exercises-that-will-keep-you-in-top-shape/) exercises that will keep you in top shape from the abdominal region.

Then to amass muscles you need all full-body powerlifting workout exercise.  Workout exercises that'll every muscle, that's your upper and lower arms and your lower and upper legs, together with healthy diets. You're good to go.